# android changing layer-list programmatically

Tags: android, xml

I have this xml drawable:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+map/marker_frame" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/map_pointer_green"/>
        <item android:id="@+map/marker_profile_picture" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/questionmark"/>
    </layer-list>
```

how can I change the item attribute from code? How can I access its id?

I want to be able to change each of the drawables from code according to scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if use [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) in your code